# Combining multiple rows to create a new row with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to modify a table format to a new format which will help me in a new .Net application I'm working on. The change is simple but I can't work it out.

Here is a sample of the current format:

```
 RecoNumber   Position  Type            Length     

 NO VON-01    Top       Spiralbelt      44.27274    
 NO VON-01    Bottom    Venta Trac      13.10656    
 ACMHAPA-01   Top       Rhino Hyde-B    28.12       
 ACMHAPA-01   Lagging   OPL-35          0           
 ADVGRMI-01   Top       Spirabelt 1.05  35.40905    
 ADVGRMI-01   Bottom    Venta Trac-B    13.05474    
 ADVGRMI-01   Lagging   BMD-6           0
```

And here is a sample of how the format should be in the end:

```
RecoNumber   TopType         BtmType       LaggingType   TopLength   BtmLength   LaggingLength   

NO VON-01    Spiralbelt      Venta Trac    NULL          44.27274    13.10656    NULL
ACMHAPA-01   Rhino Hyde-B    NULL          OPL-35        28.12       NULL        0
ADVGRMI-01   Spirabelt 1.05  Venta Trac-B  BMD-6         35.40905    13.05474    0
```

I have tried using a Group By or the Row_Number() Function to merge the but I couldn't get it to work. The closest attempt I have gotten so far is by isolating each cell but I am unable to merge them all into a single row.

Here is where I am so far:

```
SELECT  RecoNumber,
        CASE WHEN (Position = 'Top') THEN Type ELSE NULL END as TopType,
        CASE WHEN (Position = 'Top') THEN Length ELSE NULL END as TopLength,
        CASE WHEN (Position = 'Bottom') THEN Type ELSE NULL END as BtmType,
        CASE WHEN (Position = 'Bottom') THEN Length ELSE NULL END as BtmLength,
        CASE WHEN (Position = 'Lagging') THEN Type ELSE NULL END AS LaggingType,
        CASE WHEN (Position = 'Lagging') THEN Length ELSE NULL END as LaggingLength
FROM Workbook2014_Test.dbo.RecoBeltsOld

result:

RecoNumber  TopType        TopLength  BtmType      BtmLength    LaggingType    LaggingLength

NO VON-01   Spiralbelt     44.27274   NULL         NULL         NULL           NULL
NO VON-01   NULL           NULL       Venta Trac   13.10656     NULL           NULL
ACMHAPA-01  Rhino Hyde-B   28.12      NULL         NULL         NULL           NULL
ACMHAPA-01  NULL           NULL       NULL         NULL OPL-35  0
ADVGRMI-01  Spirabelt 1.05 35.40905   NULL         NULL         NULL           NULL
ADVGRMI-01  NULL           NULL       Venta Trac-B 13.05474     NULL           NULL
ADVGRMI-01  NULL           NULL       NULL         NULL         BMD-6          0
```

Thanks for any tips, Simon

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes - this is a perfectly good question, and the OP was pretty close to solving it themselves...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `group by` to get them all on the same `RecoNumber` row.

```
SELECT  RecoNumber,
        max(CASE WHEN (Position = 'Top') THEN Type ELSE NULL END) as TopType,
        max(CASE WHEN (Position = 'Top') THEN Length ELSE NULL END) as TopLength,
        max(CASE WHEN (Position = 'Bottom') THEN Type ELSE NULL END) as BtmType,
        max(CASE WHEN (Position = 'Bottom') THEN Length ELSE NULL END) as BtmLength,
        max(CASE WHEN (Position = 'Lagging') THEN Type ELSE NULL END) AS LaggingType,
        max(CASE WHEN (Position = 'Lagging') THEN Length ELSE NULL END) as LaggingLength
FROM Workbook2014_Test.dbo.RecoBeltsOld
group by RecoNumber
```

Comment: I guess you can omit using `ELSE NULL` here

Answer (score 0):

You need a self-join, along the lines of:

```
SELECT isnull(T1.RecoNumber, isnull(T2.RecoNumber, T3.RecoNumber)) AS RecoNumber, 
       T1.Type AS TopType,
       T2.Type AS BtmType, 
       T3.Type AS LaggingType,
       T1.Length AS TopLength,
       T2.Length as BtmLength, 
       T3.Type AS LaggingType
FROM   RecoBeltsOld AS T1
       FULL JOIN RecoBeltsOld AS T2 ON T2.RecoNumber = T1.RecoNumber
       FULL JOIN RecoBeltsOld AS T3 ON T3.RecoNumber = isnull(T1.RecoNumber, T2.RecoNumber)
WHERE  T1.Position = 'Top'
       AND T2.Position = 'Bottom'
       AND T3.Position = 'Lagging'
```

The `FULL JOIN` is there because I have assumed that there may not always be a top, middle and bottom record. If there is more than one matching record of each type, you may get some duplicate rows, but this should be enough to get you started...